# Delete 'note' in collection from mongoDB in Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, api

I wonder how to delete a 'note' from my mongoDB in Node.js

I'm new to Node.js, Express and mongoDB.

I'll just show my code here and let that speak for it self...

notesController.js:

```
    app.delete('/api/notes/:categoryName/:note', 
   // auth.ensureApiAuthenticated, commented when testing.
     function(req, res) {

        var categoryName = req.params.categoryName;
        var note = req.params.note;

        data.removeNote(categoryName, note, function(err, notes){
            if(err) {
                res.send(400, err);
            }
            else {
                res.send(200);
            }
        });
    });
```

index.js from data folder:

```
     data.removeNote = function(categoryName, note, next) {
    database.getDb(function(err, db){
        if(err) {
            next(err);
        }
        else {
            db.notes.remove({ note: note }, function(err, results) {
                console.log(results); //not too sure what to do here?
                next();
            });
        }
    });
};
```

MongoDB: This is the note I'm trying to delete. Not Programming since that's the category.

```
{
  "name": "Programming",
  "notes": [
    {
      "note": "Fiddler Note",
      "color": "blue",
      "author": "oOMelon"
    }
  ]
}
```

I use Fiddler when testing and I get 200 as status code... But it doesn't get deleted from the DB. Please help! :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So if I understood you correctly then you want to remove only the element within the array and not the whole document right?

Comment: Yes exactly :) sorry if I was unclear @DAXaholic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of

```
...
db.notes.remove({ note: note }, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results); //not too sure what to do here?
    next();
});
...
```

you should rather use an `update` with [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/), i.e. something like this

```
...
db.notes.update({ "notes.note": note }, 
                { $pull: { notes: { note: note } } }, 
                function(err, results) {

    console.log(results); //not too sure what to do here?
    next();
});
...
```

see the following GIF which illustrates that for your sample document.
Of course you will have to make sure that `note` is correctly set from the request data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked great! One more thing. On the client I have this angular code: $scope.removeNote = function(note) {
                $http.put(notesUrl + '/'+ note)
                .then(function (result) {
                    $scope.notes = result.data;
                }, function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            };

Comment: It works but it looks weird on the page so I have to refresh it. I have similar to this when inserting a new one When i insert a new one the note shows up without page refresh. is it possible to achieve here too? @DAXaholic